# Could quadratic variation determine distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $M=\{M_t,\mathcal{F}_t;0\le t<+\infty\}$, $N=\{N_t,\mathcal{F}_t;0\le t<+\infty\}$ be two continuous local martingales with $M_0=N_0=0\text{ a.s.}$. If $\langle M\rangle=\langle N\rangle$, then could we say that $M$ and $N$ have the same distribution?

Answer (score 4):

No, consider Brownian motion $W_t$ and
$$M_t=\frac{W_t^2-t}{2},$$
$$N_t = -M_t.$$
Source: [slides by David Heath](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/cap/Heath%20Slides.pdf) page 5.